# How could I set my datepicker to only show dates after a certain date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Question is I have a two date pickers one is for leave_start and the other is for leave_end. If someone chooses "YES" for future text_field I would like the datepicker's to then only show dates after the persons anniversary date. the one problem I might run into is the the employees anniversary date will be when they where hired so I'm not sure how I could use just the month and day of there anniversary date to only show dates for this year after their anniversary date..

So for example my name is Joe Smith and I choose a future request as "YES" and my anniversary date is 02/14/12. I want my leave_start leave_end datepickers to only show dates after 2/14 for this year. Is this possible to do? any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Basically I just don't want people picking a future request and being able to pick days before their anniversary date.

Let me know if anyone will need more information this is what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Here are my datepickers in my entry.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->

 $('#leave_start').datepicker({minDate: 0, beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });


 $('#leave_end').datepicker({minDate: 0, beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
```

Here is my view

```
=simple_form_for @entry, :url => url_for(:controller => 'entry', :action 


%td.lt= f.error :range_days, :class => 'er'


%table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
  %th.lt Indirect Code:
  %td.lt= f.input_field :indirect_id, :as => :select, :id => 'indirect_id', :label => false, :collection => ['PD', 'VAC', 'ABS'], :hint => "If you choose ABS(this is considered an unpaid absence)"
  %td.lt= f.text_field :sick_day, :id => 'sick_day', :label => "This is for if you feel the need to comment on your unpaid request", :placeholder => 'Optional Comment', :input_html => {:value => ''}
  %td.lt= f.error :indirect_id, :class => 'er'

%table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
  %th.lt Will This Request be after your anniversary date?:
  %td.lt= f.input_field :future, :as => :select, :id => 'future', :label => false, :collection => ["YES", "NO"]
  %td.lt= f.error :future, :class => 'er'

%table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
  %th.lt Leave Start:
  %td.lt= f.text_field :leave_start,  :label => false, :id => 'leave_start', :input_html => {:value => ''}
  %td.lt= f.error :leave_start, :class => 'er'

%table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
  %th.lt Leave End:
  %td.lt= f.text_field :leave_end,  :label => false, :id => 'leave_end', :input_html => {:value => ''}
  %td.lt= f.error :leave_end, :class => 'er'


%td.lt= f.text_field :range_days, :label => false, :id => 'range_days', :input_html => {:value => ''}
%td.lt= f.text_field :full_range, :label => false, :id => 'gdates', :input_html => {:value => ''}


%table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
= f.button :submit, "Submit", :class => 'customSub'
```

Here is my model for the person's anniversary date

```
class Empcomp < ActiveRecord::Base

  establish_connection :vdev

  self.table_name = 'empcomp'

  belongs_to :entry

end
```

And this is my entry controller for new and create

```
  def new
    @entry = Entry.new
    @empaccrl = Empaccrl.where("person_id = ? and is_active = 'Y'", current_user.person_id)
    @empcomp = Empcomp.where("person_id = ?", current_user.person_id)
    respond_to do |format|

      format.html# new.html.haml
      format.xml { render :xml => @entry }
    end
  end


  def create
    params.permit!
    @entry = Entry.new(params[:entry])
    @entry.t_d
    @entry.day_hours
    @entry.current_user = current_user
    @empaccrl = Empaccrl.where("person_id = ? and is_active = 'Y'", current_user.person_id)
    @empcomp = Empcomp.where("person_id = ?", current_user.person_id)
    # send my email
    respond_to do |format|

      if @entry.save
        if current_user.email.nil?
          format.html { redirect_to(entry_path( @entry ), :notice => 'Entry successfully created, but you will not recieve any notifications, because you email is blank!') }
          format.xml { render :xml => @entry, :status => :created, :location => @entry }
        else
          EntryMailer.submit_for_approval(@entry).deliver
          format.html { redirect_to(entry_path( @entry ), :notice => 'Entry successfully created.') }
          format.xml { render :xml => @entry, :status => :created, :location => @entry }
        end
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @entry.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Something like this is how I would like it to work but i cant get the anniversary date from my model. this date will be different so I cant set it as a static date

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#future').click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected == 'YES') {
     $('#leave_start').datepicker({minDate: '#anviersary_date', beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
    } else {
     $('#leave_start').datepicker({minDate: 0, beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
    }
  });
 });
```

Comment: TL;DR! You just set the `minDate` and `maxDate` setting to limit the date range

Comment: Whilst more information is usually better than too little information you might have overdone it a little here. You should try and restrict code to the code that is causing the problem. I suspect that just your coffee script would be sufficient.

Comment: I updated my question to show kind of what I would want it to do and function..@Shadwell

Comment: I updated my question to show kind of what I would want it to do and function.. @adeneo

Comment: I still think you're more likely to get better responses if you shorten and focus your question a bit more rather than adding to it.

Comment: Thank you @Shadwell I re did my question if you would like to check it out ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850690/i-want-to-be-able-to-set-a-random-date-for-my-datepicker

Answer (score 2):

That's why you have the [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) and [maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate).

On the initializer:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)
});
```

Setting after initialized:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) );
```

You don't need to post all your code here. Be specific. :)

Comment: I want this date to be based off their anniversary date which I will have multiple users with different anniversary date's.. so how could I put there anniversary date in like this  $( "#leave_start" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date('#aniversary_date') );   $( "#leave_end" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date('#aniversary_date') ); If they pick YES for future?  (((((((if they pick no the datepicker will stay the same as it is now   $('#leave_start').datepicker({minDate: 0, beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
 $('#leave_end') @Marcos Lima

Comment: You should have no problem doing this with the setter method, how you will get this date is simple js. If you have no minimum date, it should be null, not 0.

Comment: I'm not sure I am understanding this the date I want to be set for a start date would be in my rails model. how can I tell datepicker to only show dates from that date in my model I cant set the min date because the min date will always be different based off the users anniversary date @Marcos Lima

Comment: I updated my question to show kind of what I would want it to do and function..@Marcos Lima